# How can I make the binding in the CheckBox work inside a ContentPresenter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Binding in the CheckBox seems to have a problem. It throws an XamlParseException and says that two-way binding requires Path or XPath. Here is the ContentPresenter for evaluation.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PropertyValue}">
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="300"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

What I wish to accomplish is given the PropertyValue which is a polymorphic object,  and its data type, a corresponding control will be created in runtime. For instance, if the PropertyValue is a boolean property, then the control will be a checkbox. If the user toggles the checkbox, the change should be reflected on PropertyValue. If an external dependency modifies the PropertyValue (e.g.  INotifyPropertyChanged), then the checkbox must reflect that change also. Hence, I need a way to accomplish two-way binding for this.

Comment: You want it to select one of those templates based on the type of PropertyValue?  You'll probably need a TemplateSelector.

Comment: Yes. That's what I wish to accomplish

Comment: By any chance, is your question not *"why doesn't X work"* but rather *"how to make Y work"*?

Comment: @grek40 I'm sorry. :( I didn't get your question.

Comment: You are asking *"Why does binding [...] not work"* but I feel like you actually want a solution how you can make it work rather than an explanation about why it is not working.

Comment: Actually, I want to know why it does not work and what possible solution I can have. I'll modify the question

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty precise... you can't two-way bind your current `DataContext` but only a property **within** the context.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ClassTypeContainingABoolean}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourBooleanProperty}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Depending on what you actually want to do.

The whole thing is independent from the `ContentPresenter`.

---

You can use a `TemplateSelector` if you want to inspect your datacontext object, before deciding on a template.

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var elem = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (item == null || elem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var t = item.GetType();
        var prop = t.GetProperty("PropertyValue");
        if (prop == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        // select template by the type of the PropertyValue parameter
        if (typeof(bool?).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            return elem.FindResource("BooleanContextTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            return elem.FindResource("StringContextTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Data context initialization for example:

```
public class MyContextData<T>
{
    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

// initialize DataContext somewhere
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    grid1.DataContext = new MyContextData<bool>() { PropertyValue = true };
    //grid1.DataContext = new MyContextData<string>() { PropertyValue = "ABC" };
}
```

Xaml example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyContextDataTemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringContextTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyValue}" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="300"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanContextTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding PropertyValue}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyContextDataTemplateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, the `DataTemplate` that are referenced by the template selector via `FindResource("BooleanContextTemplate")` need to be defined somewhere. Also the templateselector itself is created in the resources and passed to the `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector` property.

Note that the `ContentPresenter.Content` binding is no longer targeting the `YourBooleanProperty` and this property is instead part of the templates. So in the end, your data need to be wrapped in some deterministic way, regarding the involved property names.

Comment: Why is two-way bind restricted? What I wish to accomplish is this: given the  PropertyValue, which is a polymorphic object and its data type, a corresponding control is created in runtime. For example, if the PropertyValue is boolean, I wish the control to be a checkbox. When the user toggles the checkbox, I want the change to be reflected on the PropertyValue. If PropertyValue is modified by other means (e.g. through INotifyPropertyChanged), then I want that to be reflected also to the checkbox. To accomplish that, don't I need two-way data binding?

Comment: @Xegara think of datacontext like a function parameter. With `void MyContext(object value) { var x = value; value = y; }` you can read the input, but if you try to change it, only the local value would be changed, not the value source.

Comment: Does this happen because boolean is primitive and thus it is a pass-by-value variable?

Comment: @Xegara No, it would be the same for a class object. As datacontext, you need the object that contains your property.

Comment: In order for the two way data bind to work, I would need to encapsulate the PropertyValue and use that encapsulating object as the data context?

Comment: @Xegara Yes. Maybe I'll edit the answer later to include some `TemplateSelector` as Henk Holterman suggested, but not right now.